# Does Google Gadget works for an Internal Corporate Site?

Tags: ajax, google-gadget, opensocial, mashup

We would like to use the Google Gadget concept in our corporate Intranet. Our infrastructure implies no external web dependencies.

The way I understand Google Gadget is that the gadget xml file requires some pre-processing before being displayed in a Html page:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://mysite.com/my-gadget.xml
```

Is this mean I cannot render a gadget in a Page without this pre-processing?

Thank you

Comment: You need to have web server with access to internet in order to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but it is also possible to have google widgets make use of secure data behind a firewall by using the the [Google Secure Data Connector](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/)

The browser still needs to have access to google servers to execute the widget, just data requests will be made to google and then be proxied back to a service running in your network which will then fetch the data.